# How to use the objects that are store in a list, (for sorting purposes) C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to this website, and attending a programming fundamentals course.

I'm working on my final assignment and need a bit of help.

here we go:

We have to create a simple game that has the functions of create player, load player, sorting statistics of the players.

I used this part of code to let the user enter his/her name and then store it in a list:

```
List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
Player p = new Player();
```

//the list where I store the name
//wins and losses are still set to zero

`Console.Write("Enter your Name: ");`

`nameInput = Console.ReadLine();`

`p.Name = nameInput;`

`playerList.Add(new Player(p.Name, p.Wins, p.Losses));` 
//used to add to the list

//using this method to sort by wins:

```
static void SortByWins(int playerList)
    {
        int[] arr = { 831, 12, 63, 741, 334, 851, 131, 3 };

        int temp = 0;

        for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++)
            {
                if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
                {
                    temp = arr[sort + 1];
                    arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                    arr[sort] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(arr[i] + "\n");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I used an array with some random values to check if the sorting code works, however I need so sort the wins of the players, and I don't know how to get this list into the method so it can sort the wins (also need to sort by losses and by name)
note: i'm not allowed to use the sort.Class for this assignment.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use all this. You can add `using System.Linq` at the top of your file, and then use this method:

```
playerList = playerList.OrderBy(x=> x.Wins).ToList();
```

Or:

```
playerList.Sort((x,y) => x.Wins - y.Wins);
```

Comment: @MarkHermens please write only one comment. Don't use multiple comment for one purpose.

Comment: My teacher will check this game, if he downloads the file does this mean he has to write that using system.linq into the code,

Comment: @MarkHermens It is probably already added to file by default. The second method doesn't need you to use anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to write *general purpose* code (`Sort` in your case), try to be as *general* as you can:

```
 ...
 using System.Reflection;
 ...

 public static void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer = null) {
   if (null == list)
     throw new ArgumentNullException("list"); 

   // Can we use default comparer?
   if (null == comparer) 
     if (typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) ||
         typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
       comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

   if (null == comparer)
     throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer", string.Format(
       "There's no default comparer for {0} class, you should provide it explicitly.", 
        typeof(T).Name));

   for (bool sorted = false; !sorted;) {
     sorted = true; 

     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; ++i) 
       if (comparer.Compare(list[i], list[i + 1]) > 0) {
         sorted = false;

         T h = list[i];
         list[i] = list[i + 1];
         list[i + 1] = h;  
       }
   } 
 }
```

And so you can easily sort the `playerList`:

```
 List<Player> playerList = ...

 BubbleSort(playerList, Comparer<Player>.Create((x, y) => x.Wins.CompareTo(y.Wins)));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this means I have to add                                  "using System.Reflection;" and I'm not sure if the teacher will accept that.

Comment: @Mark Hermens: well, you can omit *default comparer* part, and thus make the routine less general